# Typescript and text transformation (toLowerCase) is losing my type

Tags: javascript, typescript

Simple reproduction of my problem:

```
const demo = {
    aaa: 'aaa',
    bbb: 'bbb',
}

const input = 'AAA'

console.log(demo[input.toLowerCase()])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwLYhgXhgbwFAzzAQyIC4YByIgsgGl3wCNHSzH6bsBfbbUSWASzAAHAK6wMZAILSy3XhBAAbBADpFIAOYAKRCgDag0VBVQQAGRAB3BACcAwgQgItASgC6L7EA)

JS itself will work. It will change 'AAA' to 'aaa' which does exist in demo object.
But TS throws error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ aaa: string; bbb: string; }'.
```

It's because it sees this value as any String, not 'aaa'. So TS does not allow to any text transformations in it's compiler?

This uppercase value comes from API (graphql enum) so I'm not able to change that. In other hand this object comes from library that uses normal pascalCase keys. So how I can connect both without TS complaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to assert is that `input.toLowerCase()` results in a valid key for the map `demo`. You can express that like this:

```
console.log(demo[input.toLowerCase() as keyof typeof demo])
```

This should give you full type safety in the surrounding code. This is fine:

```
let ok: 'aaa' | 'bbb' = demo[input.toLowerCase() as keyof typeof demo]
```

But these are rejected:

```
let error1: 'aaa' = demo[input.toLowerCase() as keyof typeof demo]
let error2: 'ccc' = demo[input.toLowerCase() as keyof typeof demo]
```

Comment: But it will result as "any" type, so I'm still losing typing, and TS will complain in all other parts of code due to "any" type

Comment: You are right. Edited with a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what **@Thomas** said in the above answer,

Whenever you use `Typescript`, You should clearly define the types of the `variables` and `objects`.

Check out the below code.

```
type d = {
    [key: string]: string
}

const demo: d = {
    aaa: 'aaa',
    bbb: 'bbb',
}

const input: string = 'AAA'

console.log(demo[input.toLowerCase()])
```

Comment: It will make error go away, so point for that, but it's losing any bug detection. We can change input to 'BBB' and TS will not detect that 'bbb' does not exist on demo object since this "d" type allows all strings as keys which is not the case.